# mysql log table with timestamp - need to read timestamp back

Tags: php, mysql, logging, timestamp

I have a log table that records user activity and has a time stamp created with the following

```
function user_log($user_name, $log_data){
 $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `logs` (user_id, time_stamp, activity, ip) VALUES ('$user_name', now(), '$log_data', '$ipaddress')");
```

}

as you can see, I have used the `now()` function.
However my problem is that I would like to be able to delete the logs older than say 28 days (2419200 seconds).

To do so I have tried the following...

```
$past_date = mktime()-2419200;
mysql_query("DELETE * FROM logs WHERE time_stamp<'$past_date'");
```

however it doesn't work, and I suspect that there is a different in formats that I am missing.

Thanks in advance,

Cam

Answer (score 0):

The date format MySQL uses is

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

Example

```
2013-03-31
```

Try

```
DELETE * FROM logs WHERE time_stamp < curdate() - 28 day
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysql_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($past_date))
```

Something like this you have to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
DELETE * FROM logs WHERE time_stamp <= NOW() - INTERVAL 28 DAY
```